# JSON/PHP array error

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to save an array to export it to a JSON file, but it's not working...
I want to save it like this:

```
$uid => $name:$link
```

I tried this:

```
$data = array($uid => array($name => $link));
```

But now it's saving it like this: {"Arrow":"679/arrow"} without the $uid

- the uid is the userid and stands for the user, I would like the arrays to store their favorite movies/series.

Comment: Please post more of the surrounding code. The single line you supplied here is syntactically valid.

Comment: The error should tell you the line of code that has the error. Is it the line of code you showed us?

Comment: Yes, but I found the bug. That part doesn't matter anymore.

Comment: As mentioned, please post more code. There's nothing wrong with that line, but often an error on a previous line will result in a parsing problem later, and the error points to the later line.

Comment: Do a `print_r()` for `$uid` `$name` and `$link` and post the output for us.

Comment: But now it's saving it like this: {"Arrow":"679\/arrow"} without the $uid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
$data[$uid][$name]=$link;
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is encode that array to JSON using [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
$data = array($uid => array($name => $link));
echo json_encode($data);
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/131392)**

Comment: He is getting an error when trying to create the `$data` array.

Comment: I believe this is no longer an issue see op [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844639/json-php-array-error/22846094#comment34848282_22844639)